# internal SSD crash. macbook retina early 2016. Mac OS X el capitan

Tags: hard-drive, macos, ssd, filesystem, performance

My macbook crashed after an ongoing update.
I get the "?" file when rebooting it.
After several test i decided to reformat my SSD as it was impossible to install a new version of mac OS X on it.
At this point, the SSD is crashing the reformat or erase process from diskutil. when i launched them. The system is starting to unmount the drive. Then freezing after 30 seconds approximately.

Here are the details of the hard drive and the errors
[image: diskutil view]

the problem is disk0
[image: diskutil general info]

the gpt show command is showing this
[image: the gpt show command is showing this]

when i try to repair the volume
[image: when i try to repair the volume]

when i try to repair the disk
[image: when i try to repair the disk]

Thanks a lot for the support
Paul

Comment: Can you install the OS onto an external drive to validate that the image and computer are sound? I’d hate to have you repair the SSD or replace it if it’s. It the cause.

Comment: Yes. I have a bootable USB key with Mac OS X on it. Not really fast but the MacBook is working correctly

Comment: You can merge accounts if needed with the contact us link. No need to, just an option if you find you end up with several accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re not sure you are doing the full erase correctly, you can follow this guide. It will repartition the drive erasing everything on it and let you attempt a clean os installation.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354246/5472

If you’re not ready for that, consider installing on to an external drive to back up any files and make sure it’s not something other than the SSD failing or needing to erase everything first.

Comment: I already did that. if i am erasing the hard drive. the disk utility is starting the process. but then, the window is blocked at "unmounted disk" and the macbook is shutting down.

Comment: That is a potential hardware failure mode - it’s where it says contact service in the Apple KB linked in my other post. Hope it’s not @paulkarpat